# Building code in Canada

Tags: building-regulations

Are there any online resources for determining building code requirements in Canada?

For example right now I need to know what the proper diameter for a dryer vent to the outside should be. Last week I needed to know how high a flight of stairs can be before hand railings are required . I called the local municipal building inspectors' office to get the answer (24", 60cm). It was successful, but it took 3 attempts to get a hold of someone in the office who could answer. Surely there's an easier more direct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [Canada's National Building Code](http://www.nationalcodes.ca/eng/nbc/index.shtml), but unfortunately they seem only to sell copies of it on CD or printed form.

Comment: hmm, looks like there is an [online subscription version](https://commerce-irc.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/nrcb2c/catalog/setCurrentItem/%28isQuery=yes&xcm=NRC-R3PITREX&query=national+construction+code&layout=6_1_60_57_5_2&uiarea=2&ctype=areaDetails&next=seeItem&carea=0000000038&citem=00000000400000000003%29/.do) also. $125 for one year, or $35 for 10 days. A reasonable price if you're in the business but that's pretty steep for a homeowner with only occasional, but strong, need. Thanks.

Comment: If I recall correctly, you'll need a provincial code for this information.  The national code is more for engineers, and provincial codes are for builders.

Answer (score 0):

In BC go to [the BC Building Code site](http://www.bccodes.ca/bccode_building.htm).  There are a variety of subscription options.  The search and index is acceptably good, I have used it extensively.